# How to move values from InputFields to variables in GameObject script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game that simulates projectile motion on a sphere and all I need for the user to provide is the amount of gravity, the launch angle and the speed.

In order to get this input I made a canvas and attached it to the main camera along with three different input fields (Renamed Angle, Speed and Grav). **However I'm not sure how to get the input from these fields and transfer them to already existing variables in the sphere's script.**
So far I have:

```
public class SphereJump : MonoBehaviour{

public InputField Speed;
public InputField Grav;
public InputField Angle;

//The following are the three variables required to calculate trajectory in 
later calculations
public float gravity = float.Parse(Grav.text);
public float InitialSpeed = float.Parse(Speed.text);
public float LaunchAngle = float.Parse(Angle.text);
```

To be honest I don't think float.parse is necessary since I changed the content type of all three input fields to decimal number, but nevertheless I get an error stating **"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property".**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables to initialize other variables the way you want in your global scope. You would have to change gravity, InitialSpeed and LaunchAngle to static. Normally you do the initialization in class constructors. In Unity3D with MonoBehaviour you usually do it in the Start() or Awake() method.

Do this instead:

```
public InputField Speed;
public InputField Grav;
public InputField Angle;
public float gravity;
public float InitialSpeed;
public float LaunchAngle;

private void Start()
{
    gravity = float.Parse(Grav.text);
    InitialSpeed = float.Parse(Speed.text);
    LaunchAngle = float.Parse(Angle.text);
}
```

It is nothing wrong in using the float.Parse() here. It is always better to make sure the value passed to your variables from a text field is of right type.